# MeteorJS 0.9.0 - package for fullPage.js. Page works on refresh but not when linked to.

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, package, fullpage.js

I created my first Meteor package for fullPage.js. This package uses Meteor's new packaging system.

On first page load the package works great. Normal autoscrolling between sections as expected.

Linking to another page within the app will initialize fullPage without any errors. However, after scroll or down arrow click, the page autoscrolls and skips sections. Refreshing the page fixes the problem.

Setting "autoScrolling: false" will stop the page from scrolling to the bottom after initial scroll. However, this then causes the app to use normal scrolling.

Package dependencies: 
    [
      "jquery",
      "1.0.0"
    ],
    [
      "meteor",
      "1.0.2"
    ],
    [
      "mrt:jquery-ui",
      "1.9.2"
    ],
    [
      "underscore",
      "1.0.0"
    ]

An example of the problem: http://fullpagetest.meteor.com/

The package: https://github.com/lawshe/full-page

Comment: A possible connection, there are multiple #fp-nav elements when the autoscroll problem appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are initializating the plugin each time you click in a menu.

You don't want to initialize fullpage.js more than once.
I would recommend you to avoid using AJAX and just use normal links for each section.

Otherwise, you should make use of the function [`$.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#destroytype)  every time you click in a link and then initialize fullpage.js again as you are doing right now.

The `destroy('all')` function will remove all the plugin events (mousewheel, scroll...) and all the changes made over your original structure (addition of classes, inline styles...).
In other words, it will just restart your HTML structure as it was before applying fullpage.js.

Once that is done, fullpage.js can be initialized again.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro! Adding a click event to destroy the fullpage instance fixed the problem.